# ld: file not found: -Obj-C error when building a new XCode project using embeded Cordova webview

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, webview, linker

I am trying to create a basic iOS app with Cordova webview. I followed the cordova [instructions for iOS webView](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_ios_webview.md.html#iOS%20WebViews). Specifically step 11 asked me to these two option into `other linker flags` field in the target:

```
-force_load
-Obj-C
```

When I try to buid the project I get the following error at the end:

```
ld: file not found: -Obj-C
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am pretty new to iOS, but to me it looks as linker thinks I am passing it a path as opposed to an option. Is this due to changes in XCode or am I doing something wrong? I am using the latest (v5.0.2) of xcode. I'd appreciate any help.

**Edit**: I found a workaround
My goal was to start an xcode project with a cordova webview. Actually when we create a new app with cordova command line tool and add the `ios` platform to it, cordova will also generate an xcode project for us. When I open the project I can edit the `MainViewContorller.m` or add other libraries or SDKs to the project. So my problem has been solved.

I am still curious as why the instructions in the official documentation did not work. If you know why, feel free to share.

Comment: Did you have instrutions on how to do the work around to pay attention to a story board instead of the provided MainViewController.xib?

Comment: @gregavola like I said in my edit, just create a new cordova project and add ios platform to it, then take a look inside the `platform/ios` folder

Comment: I've done this, but it already includes the MainViewController.xib - and I'm looking to use a StoryBoard and add the CordovaWebView to the ViewControllers.

Comment: @gregavola I am not sure. Try asking a new question, or maybe ask in the #phonegap irc channel

Comment: @Aras : I had same issue and switch to same work-around..

Answer (score 1):

It works just by deleting option
`-force_load`
and replacing option
`-Obj-C` with `-ObjC`

Answer (score 0):

Linker flag should be `-ObjC`, not `-Obj-C`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Vladimir. I tried `-ObjC` as well but I am getting the same error (except this time it is complaining about `-ObjC`)

Comment: May you upload your project to GitHub (or some other publicly accessible location)?

Comment: the project is `opios-cordova` that my coleague linked to. I took out the code related to cordova, but I will push it again in a separate branch later today and will let you know in the comment. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: thanks again for trying to help. I found a workaround that is much nicer, so I am going to move on and use command line generated project instead (see the update in my question). Cheers!